# show datePicker in Xamarin.Forms when click Frame Layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am doing an application using Xamarin.Forms. There I need to show a datePicker when clicks on a Frame layout. For that purpose I have done this.

**xaml part**

```
<Frame Margin="15,0,15,5" HasShadow="false" OutlineColor="{StaticResource TextColorBlue}" BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="selectDate" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" IsVisible="false" DateSelected="Handle_DateSelected" TextColor="Maroon" />
                <Label Text="Date" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColorBlue}" />
                <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Silver" HeightRequest="1" />
                <Grid RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="Saturday" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColorBlue}" />
                    <Label Text="May" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColorBlue}" />
                    <Label Text="20" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColorBlue}" />
                    <Label Text="2017" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColorBlue}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="Handle_Tapped_DatePicker" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Frame>
```

**cs part**

```
void Handle_Tapped_DatePicker(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Handle_Tapped_DatePicker");
        if (datePicker.IsFocused)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Yes, datePicker is focused");
            datePicker.Unfocus();
        }

        datePicker.Focus();
    }

    void Handle_DateSelected(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("e.NewDate: " + e.NewDate.ToString());
    }
```

But nothing happening here. The datePicker is not showing. I am testing on iOS simulator. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully I got the answer after some searches.
The thing is that, You need to bring the focus of datePicker through the `device main UI thread`. I have changed my code like this.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            if (datePicker.IsFocused)
                datePicker.Unfocus();
            datePicker.Focus();
        });
```